# React Native signed apk fails after upgrading the gradle build tool version to 3.2.1

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

After upgrading the following line in the build.gradle file

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`

and below line in gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

the signed release apk of my app is not working at all. Though when I am running the app in development mode everything is working fine.

Below is the error i am getting in the android studio logcat -

> 2018-11-23 17:49:24.552 3506-3570/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   Thread-2
>       Process: com.simplydatanow.driverapp, PID: 3506
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or
>   you're running a packager server.
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native
>   Method)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:216)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:33)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:234)
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1137)
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$900(ReactInstanceManager.java:113)
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:944)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

This is the signed release apk, so index.android.bundle should be already present inside the apk. But somehow it is not able to find that. Any help is appreciated.

All dependecies in package.json -

```
"dependencies": {
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"polished": "^1.9.2",
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.52.0",
"react-native-auth0": "^1.2.2",
"react-native-background-fetch": "^2.4.3",
"react-native-background-task": "^0.2.1",
"react-native-compress-image": "^2.0.1",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-document-picker": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-elements": "^0.19.0",
"react-native-fab": "^1.0.8",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
"react-native-floating-action": "^1.13.0",
"react-native-fs": "^2.10.14",
"react-native-image-cache-hoc": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.10",
"react-native-image-progress": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-image-to-pdf": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.24",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.5.0",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-view": "^0.0.14",
"react-native-pdf": "^5.0.9",
"react-native-progress": "^3.4.0",
"react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.8.0",
"react-native-simple-dialogs": "^0.4.1",
"react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.8",
"react-native-timer-component": "^1.0.2",
"react-native-uuid-generator": "^4.0.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
"react-navigation": "^2.14.2",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"redux": "^3.7.2"
```

},

Answer (score 0):

change version code and version name in build.gradle(Module:app)

Go to Build-->Generate Signed Bundle or Apk--> choose APK--> click on 'Next'--> Enter keystore credentials or if you don't have create it--> check both V1 and V2 in signature versions--> click on finish to generate signed APK.

Upload this APK to playstore